# MySQL Using LIMIT vs OFFSET

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

What's the difference between

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 50 OFFSET 5

SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5,50
```

Is the second just a shorter version without using the OFFSET clause, or does writing is as an argument give better performance?

Comment: The two are just alternative syntaxes for the same thing.

Comment: No difference- and both of them are absent an ORDER BY clause, which renders them fairly meaningless

Comment: They are alternative syntax for the same thing. I would argue that `OFFSET` always has bad performance, but that's another story. Use "key set" pagination if you can.

Comment: Also, please not that `OFFSET` without `ORDER BY` doesn't make any sense.